# How to create new account/Signup on Tealium IQ

Tags: tealium

I want to learn Tealium Tag management and wanted to create a test account but can't find any Signup option anywhere. even to create a helpdesk ticket it needs to log in.

Any Idea how to create a Tealium IQ account?

https://my.tealiumiq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Tealium IQ is an enterprise tag management solution, and thus there is no free version i believe. However, you can try writing an email to **education.support@tealium.com**, asking them to setup an account by mentioning you purpose.

I am not really sure if they may but you can still try.

Happy Learning! :)